# Laravel redirect->back() return empty params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a **index.blade.php** page, I have a this code that shows alerts success or errors:

```
    <!-- ALERTS -->
    @if (isset($msg))
        @if ($msg_type == 'error')
            <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ $msg }}</div>
        @else
            <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{ $msg }}</div>
        @endif
        <script>setTimeout("document.getElementById('mensajecarrito').style.display='none'",6000);</script>
    @endif
    <!-- //ALERTS -->
```

This index have a form, and this form url POST to the post_designs url, and this is his controller method:

```
public function postDesign() {

        if (Session::has('FUNCTION'))
                $function = Session::get('FUNCTION');

            if (Input::has('FUNCTION'))
                $function = Input::get('FUNCTION'); 

            if (isset($function))
            {           
                switch($function)
                {
                    case 'createDesign':   

                        try
                        {   
                            //do something good
                            $msg_type = 'success';                      
                            $msg = 'Design created successfully';     
                        }
                        catch(FotiApiException $e)
                        {
                            $msg_type = 'error';                    
                            $msg = 'Unexpected error';       
                        }

                    break;
                }                           
            }



        return back()->with(array('msg' => $msg, 'msg_type' => $msg_type));
    }
```

**The problem is, that the $msg and $msg_type variables are empty when return back to my index.blade.php...**

I don´t understand, my project is Laravel 5.2.3 and I have the correct route Middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () {

    # Index
    Route::get('/',['as'=> 'index','uses' => 'WebController@getIndex']);

    // # POSTS
    Route::post('/post-design', ['as' => 'post_design', 'uses' => 'WebController@postDesign']);

});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use withInput()

```php
return back()->withInput(array('msg' => $msg, 'msg_type' => $msg_type));
```

the data saved in session
if you want to use the data in blade.
try use old('msg') or old('msg_type')

```html
@if(old('msg'))
<p>msg:{{ old('msg') }}<p>
@endif
```

php

```php
$msg = $request->old('msg');
```

[laravel requests old-input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#old-input)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send some extra GET parameters then simply follow below.

```
$previousUrl = app('url')->previous();

return redirect()->to($previousUrl.'?'. http_build_query(['varName'=>'varValue']));
```

It will redirect with **yoururl?varName=varValue**, hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
return back()->with('msg', $msg)->with('msg_type', $msg_type);
```

use

```
return back()->withInput(['msg' => $msg, 'msg_type' => $msg_type]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function

```
return back()->with('msg', $msg)
```

It doesn't return data to the usual variables and not to

```
request()->get("msg") or $msg
```

It returns data to

```
session()->get("msg")
```

and you can use it to get the variables you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with laravel 5.2, about routes there is no need to but routes in

```
['middleware' =>[ 'web']]
```

scene  all routes in laravel 5.2 goes in it , so try to remove it

---

and to return view with 2 values try to make it like that :

```
 return back()->with('msg', $msg)->with('msg_type', $msg_type);
```

I hope that fixes the problem :)